# My intellij java project can't find misc.xml

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I have a java project in Intellij and use Hg/Mercurial for version control. I ignored some files with this `.hgignore` file

```
syntax: glob
target/*
.idea/*
*.iml
```

and deleted all these files which was committed before. but now I can't execute my project, cause it can not find the file `misc.xml`.

What should I do?

Comment: Try restoring the deleted file using the [Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/restoring-a-file-from-local-history.html) feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, you shouldn't really ignore everything under .idea but instead only .idea/workspace.xml and .idea/tasks.xml, as it JetBrains states: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1186

To solve your problem and get your project back to working state there are possibly two solutions:

- Checkout the last commit that contains the files under .idea folder with
  `hg checkout SHA`,
  where SHA is the commit id.

  After that reset your working space to the head:

  `hg reset HEAD`

  Edit your .hgignore in the way that was recommended before, add project files to stage, and commit them:

  `hg commit -am "Reverted project settings"`
- If there is no commit with the project settings, you can just import your code back.
  Start Intellij IDEA and choose "Import Project". Choose the folder with your code, and choose the appropriate SDK after.

Comment: `hg reset`, seriously?

Answer (score 13):

Updated answer for IntelliJ 14+: **File-> New-> Project from Existing Sources...** (choose your project directory) and follow the wizard Q&A.

Comment: In latest version, this has no effect if the project is already open (I think intellij sees that the new project is already there and hence does nothing). Instead you can close the current project and click on Import a project which will let you overwrite the existing project.

Comment: Rubbal, dude what you said should have beeen the best answer. The 2 answers above requited an extreme ammount of researching to just make em work. I did as you said and itnellij auto created missing files and it just worked

Answer (score 12):

Restarting Intellij should fix the problem. Just make sure you click on the "Import Project" pop-up that appears on the top right.

Answer (score 7):

I met this problem when I did `rm -rf project` command, then when I git clone a new project to my working space, maybe quit the idea and then import the project again. This can easily solve this

Answer (score 2):

I have found that for this error and also for some other cases where the IDE project behavior is inconsistent with command line behavior, the following often helps: close the project's Intellij IDEA window, delete .idea/, and open the project again.  IntelliJ often flashes up a message saying it didn't find a project root but generally this disappears after a few seconds and IntelliJ automatically rebuilds the .idea directory.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating the .idea folder

- File -> Close project
- File -> Open -> Choose pom.xml under the project folder -> Open as project -> Delete existing project and import